# Using vectors with objects error

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

It's been awhile since I've done C++ so I'm having a bit of trouble here. I'm getting this error on the line where I declare `allQueue` in the main file. I've obviously stripped out a lot of code that I don't think is required, if you need anything more let me know.

Compiling with

```
g++ mainFile.cpp MyClass.cpp extraObjectFile.o -o mainFile
```

Generates:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token
```

**main file**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>    
#include "MyClass.h"

vector<MyClass> allQueue;
int main()
{
   allQueue.push_back(new MyClass(100));
}
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(int start_priority)
{
    priority = start_priority;
}


int MyClass::getPriority()
{
    return priority;
}
```

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass
{
    int priority;
    public:
        MyClass(int);
        int getPriority();
};
```

Comment: Since nobody explains _why_ to add `std::` before `vector`, and since its not worthy of its own answer, it is because the `vector` template belongs to the `std` namespace. An alternative would be to have `using namespace std;` after your includes. See [http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/)

Comment: right. I copied some code from an old cpp file I wrote a couple years ago and I was comparing this file to my old one and I must have forgot to copy the namespace line. never would have found it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, first thing to note: When you post an error message, please post the *full* error message your compiler gave you. Otherwise, nobody might be able to help you.

Secondly, the answer to your question:

Use

```
std::vector<MyClass> allQueue;
```

in your main.cpp file. And do a

```
allQueue.push_back(MyClass(100));
```

to add objects. Consider implementing a copy constructor for MyClass also.

Comment: +1 this took away all compiler errors. Is it considered better practice to use `vector<MyClass>` or `vector<MyClass*>` ?

Comment: @jb It depends on what you want to store. One stores a pointer, the other the object itself. For most cases you want to simply store the object. Keep in mind when storing pointers you still have to `delete` them when erasing from the `vector` or else you get a memory leak.

Comment: @jb. Whether you use a MyClass or a MyClass* as the container element for the vector depends entirely on what you want to achieve. Both approaches have their pro's and con's. However, a lot of people would argue that using MyClass is safer, and only if you really have to use pointers, you should consider using a smart pointer (such as boost::shared_ptr from Boost or std::shared_ptr if you already have C++ 11 support).

Answer (score 1):

Change `vector` to `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `std::vector`, not simply `vector`.
2. Operator `new` returns a pointer to `MyClass`, not an object itself. You need make a vector of pointers (`vector<MyClass*>`) or you need to use `MyClass()` constructor like this

   `MyClass m(100);
   allQueue.push_back(m);`

or simply that

```
allQueue.push_back(mMyClass(100));
```